# How to find the value of the variable by using the Cramer's rule (Python)?

Tags: python, math, matrix

The problem is, x + 3y − 2 = 1,3 + 2 + 6 = −2,2 + 4 + 3 = 2 .
I want to know the value of the ,,and  by using the Cramer's rule.
Well, what I've done is hardcoded stuff but the instruction restricted the 'solve' function. Additionally, this link is the additional information about the [Cramer's Rule](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/cramers.htm) .

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.linalg import solve

a = np.matrix([[1, 3, -2], [3, 2, 6], [2, 4, 3]])
b = np.matrix([[1], [-2], [2]])

top_of_x = np.matrix([[1, 3, -2], [-2, 2, 6], [2, 4, 3]])
det_of_top_of_x = np.linalg.det(top_of_x)
det_of_a = np.linalg.det(a)
x = det_of_top_of_x / det_of_a
print x
```

Comment: `np.linalg.solve(a, b)` directly solves the linear equation, although I don't know if it uses Cramer's Rule.

Comment: Could you please add a link or a short explanation of 'Cramer's rule' as not everybody may be familiar with it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I totally forgot about that point.

Comment: If you have working code and are trying to find ways to improve it, post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Already fixed that link. Thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to "compute" the matrices given `A` and `b`.

```
AT = A.T # get an array of the matrix columns
top_of_x = np.matrix(b, AT[1], AT[2])
top_of_y = np.matrix(AT[0], b, AT[2])
top_of_z = np.matrix(AT[0], AT[1], b)
```

etc.

Or if you do not want to change `A`

```
top_of_x = A.copy()
top_of_x[:,0] = b
```

and so on

---

The last approach using vectors and indices, this also works for all dimensions, but gets increasingly wasteful, as its effort is O(n^4) operations, while a simple LU decomposition and triangular backwards substitution is O(n^3).

```
det_A = np.linalg.det(A); # uses LU decomposition, which is the main part of solve
top = A.copy();
x = np.zeros_like(A[0])
for k in range(len(x)):
    top[:,k] = b;
    x[k] = np.linalg.det(top)/det_A;
    top[:,k] = A[:,k];  # restore column for next computation
print x
```